# Can't save high score in Unreal Engine blueprints

Tags: unreal-4, savegame, blueprints

I'm trying to make a pinball game in Unreal Engine with blueprints, but the high score does not save.

You have 2 lives while playing, and after the game ends this save game function executes. The game is storing the variable (I know because the print string node at the end of function outputs the correct amount/score after each game) but the high score does not appear in the HUD of the game.

[image: Image of blueprint that saves score]

[image: Image of blueprint that displays score]

Comment: Your newly added image seems to show fetching the health value from the player character, not the high score value from a HighScoreSave. Did you upload the correct image? Or is there some intermediate step we're missing?

Comment: yes my bad i uploaded the wrong image, corrected now

Comment: When does this high score function get called/invoked? Where does variable 0 get a value assigned to it? Notice how many follow-up questions we're needing to ask in order to fully understand your problem: that's a sign that you have not shared a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example as required for troubleshooting questions. Try creating a new, empty project and implement just the bare minimum in that project to load, save, and display a number, and record every step you take. Then post those complete instructions so a reader can reproduce the problem exactly.